# Yii2 assign id field on create

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I am using Yii2 and MongoDB and I need to create a record with a preset _id field.

The _id is a MongoId so it is unique. No issues of conflicting ids here.

I am creating a CSS theme template system where the #id selector in CSS uses the id of the theme model.

I can generate the id on the controller level add it as a hidden field.

The question is how do I override the default behaviour where _id is generated by the model with my own _id

Comment: Great to know you can do that, so...what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by adding a "create" scenario and adding a rule to set _id to "safe" on the scenario on my model:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['_id'], 'safe', 'on' => 'create']
    ];
}
```